# Считаются ли родственными следующие слова – греч. ΓΔΕΡΝΩ и английское STRIP?

Tags: этимология

Считаются ли родственными следующие слова – греч. ΓΔΕΡΝΩ и английское STRIP?

Очень похоже, что оба эти слова получились из русского корня ДИР (С+ДИР), от слова СДИРАТЬ.

Другими словами, когда греки и англичане заимствовали это слово из русского "словаря" каждый перенес его на бумагу так, как слышал, т.е. вместе с приставкой "С". А потом уже утвердились нормы этих языков, которые и узаконили оба эти корня: в греческом - ΓΔΕΡ(ГДЕР от русс. СДИР, СДИРАТЬ) а в английском - STR (СДР от СДИРАТЬ).

В итоге получилось два симпатичных слова из одного корня-основы. Или это не так?

Поясню свою мысль. Она вне канонов лингвистики. Однако, тоже имеет право на жизнь:
Нам известны русские корни, перешедшие, по нашему же мнению, в языки западной Европы.
При этом, одно и то же русское слово разные европейские народы могли слышать и записывать по разному. Отсюда и наша гипотеза, что ΓΔΕΡΝΩ и STRIP - результат заимствования русс.СДИРАТЬ. Не смотря на кажущееся их различие.

PS. Кстати, не подумайте, что это некий единичный или даже редкий пример. Таковых - предостаточно. Иначе не было бы никакого смысла затевать столь "сомнительный" разговор со специалистами языка.

Comment: @Федя. А вот русское слово БАЛДА тоже, должно быть,  послужило первоосновой для английских слов ball (=мяч) и ballon (=сосуд,  баллон).  БАЛДА это же тот,  кто во дворе в футбол гоняет,  вместо того,  чтобы уроки делать или аэрозоль из баллончика себе в нос пускает - т.е. токсикоман.

Answer (score 1):

обдирное зерно - шелуху обдирают, а это грязь, уз(д)ерно--в греческом?, это то что с зерном можно сотворить, перетереть в муку, транскрипция.. 
Grass-трава в английском. А у нас дерн-трава с землей. graas-пастбище в нидерландском.
Завязок таких пруд пруди. Зерно действительно очищают. А семечки грызут. Зерно еще и груз, а в греческом χρυσός это-золото. https://translate.google.ru/#en/ru/graze
Вот когда Анализ по многим языкам провести, да синонимы учесть, технологии, экономику, географию, то что имеем с ГУСЯ?-Дерн

дерн род. п. дёрна, укр. де́рен, русск.-цслав. дьрнъ, болг. дрън, словен. dr̀n, род. п. dŕna, чеш. drn, польск. darn, darń, в.-луж. dorn, н.-луж. dern. Родственно др.-инд. dīrṇáṣ "лопнувший, расколотый", кимр. darn "кусок, часть" и, далее, русск. деру́, драть. Ср. лит. dìrti "снимать дерн"; см. Миклошич (Mi. EW 42), Бернекер (1, 256), Педерсен (Kelt. Gr. 1, 52), Лиден (Stud. 96), Перссон (672), Младенов (153) против Сольмсена (KZ 35, 474), который сравнивает это слово, что менее убедительно, с греч. θρόνος "пестрый", лат. frons, frondis "листва". Др.-русск. дьрнъ "присяга" объясняется обычаем класть кусок дерна на голову при принесении присяги. Отсюда др.-русск. грамота дьрноватая, дьрная "грамота, скрепленная присягой" (Срезн. I, 654). Сюда же др.-русск. одьрнь, одерень "целиком, вполне". Излишне предположение Бернекера (там же) о незасвидетельствованном знач. "шкура"; ср. Брюкнер, AfslPh 39, 2. Этимологический словарь русского языка. — М.: Прогресс М. Р. Фасмер 1964—1973 
А травинку можно и погрызть, если грусть по другой пище одолела.

Со стрип стриппер--только косвенно--зерноуборочный комбайн, полосу зерновых косит, стрижет, обмолачивает, убирает.
А в остальном никак.

stripper: варианты перевода

съемник puller, stripper, remover, lifter
стриппер
stripper, gleaner
отпарная колонна
stripper
колосоуборщик
stripper
исполнительница стриптиза
stripper, peeler

Не делайте поспешных выводов, и все тогда получится. Над каждым вроде как совпадением, надо с месячишко поработать тщательно.

Comment: Догадываюсь, что Вы сообщаете что-то интересное. Но не могли бы Вы еще раз это рассказать, только яснее и лаконичнее?

Comment: Гле-то я уже это слышал...

Answer (score -1):

Похоже, вы попутали божий дар с яичницей.

strip--полоса в английском, А γδερνω-стирать, перетираться и др. кстати, озвучивается как узерно. сдирают--это в стриптизе :)

Comment: Не путайте:
англ. STRIPPER - ЗАЧИСТКА
англ. GRAZE - ОБДИРАТЬ (от русс. ГРЫЗТЬ)
А наш с Вами английский глагол STRIP (а не существительное!) во втором значении имеет ЗАЧИЩАТЬ.
Вот я и предположил, что англ.STRIP - от русс. СДИРАТЬ (приставка слилась с корнем).

А греч.ΓΔΕΡΝΩ близко рус. ДЕР, ДРАТЬ. Приставка "С" слилась с греч. в коренную "Г".
Так же в англ. есть еще слово от того же русс-го - GRAZE (ГРЫЗТЬ).
Все три приведенных мной слова имеют схожую семантику и графику, хотя и выглядят на первый взгляд по разному.
Можно найти и другие слова с похожим значением от русского корня ДИР.